# How to add a project ActionBar ViewPage Swipe using SupportLibrary AppcomptV7?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

The question is not as complex as it seems.
I made this design based on some tutorials on the internet.
I have a tabbed browsing with swipe using SupportLibrary for devices prior to Honeycomb can visualize.

Now I want to add a ActionBar in the application. Also by using the SuportLibrary appcompat.v7.

I've used the appcompat.v7 to create an application with ActionBar compatible with older versions of Android.

What I'm not getting now and join these two navigational structures.

I really want to add to this mu ActionBar project with swipe tabs below:

**MainActivity**:

```
package br.com.wgbn.poemadodiav2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        TitleAdapter titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**TitleAdapter**:

```
package br.com.wgbn.poemadodiav2;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

public class TitleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private String titles[] = new String[]{"O Poema do Dia","Comentários"};
        private Fragment frags[] = new Fragment[titles.length]; 

        public TitleAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
                frags[0] = new FragmentView1();
                frags[1] = new FragmentView2();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position){
                Log.v("TitleAdapter - getPageTitle=", titles[position]);
                return titles[position];
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Log.v("TitleAdapter - getItem=", String.valueOf(position));
                return frags[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return frags.length;
        }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/viewpager"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pagerTabStrip"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cccccc"/>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the image of the app working so far.

[image]

I hope you can help me.

#### EDIT

Following the guidance of NikolaDespotoski, decided the issue only changing the extension class for ActionBarActivity!
Actually I was thinking it had to implement the two things together, without realizing that ActionBarActivity already encompassed both.
My code looked like this, and it worked:

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // code here
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are not even extending to ActionBarActivity, for starters. Have no worries ActionBarActivity wraps up also FragmentActivity, and you'd be allowed to access FragmentManager in same manner as you do in FragmentActivity. :)

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I do not really stretched the ActionBarActivity up having to extend the FragmentActivity because I need him to swipe tabs.
It has to extend the two simultaneously, and ActionBarActivity FragmentsActivity?

Comment: Nope, just extend to ActionBarActivity, you'll still be able to swipe tabs (use fragments) and have support actionbar.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Let me get this straight, if I extend the ActionBarActivity will be bringing together the resources of fragments?

Comment: You need to extend to ActionBarActivity and add Theme.AppCompat theme. See this video from Android Team https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Thank you! Actually I was thinking it had to implement the two things together, without realizing that ActionBarActivity already encompassed both.
My code looked like this, and it worked:
`package br.com.wgbn.poemadodiav2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
// code here 
}`